# Sumifs with or conditional in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sumifs

I have a database and I need to create a `sumifs` expression in Google sheets with the following rules: I have a range of cells and this would be a filter for what the `sumifs` must sum (similar to an OR). I think the image will explain a little bit better what my expected result is:

[image: a spreadsheet displaying the result of summing a certain column based on the values of another column]

I have been trying with a lot of examples but none of them have given me the right result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the values and then sum up:

[image]

First one would be: `=SUM(FILTER($B$1:$B$6;$A$1:$A$6=$F$4:$F$6))`

Second one: `=SUM(FILTER($B$1:$B$6;$A$1:$A$6=$I$4:$I$5))`

You can see an [example I uploaded to GDrive](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kfoyNtoSfzC_EslHfkwVnWvITGdmsgBJIdkbBx26EEs/edit?usp=sharing)